# Showing the title bar when JFrame is in fullscreen doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I just wrote a program that shows a `JFrame` in fullscreen mode ***without the title bar***. However this makes the `JFrame` difficult to close. (The user has to press `Alt` + `F4` to do so). What I want is that the title bar appears when the user moves the mouse very near to the top of the `JFrame` (say 1 pixel from the top). This is just the same feature that fullscreen windows have in Windows 10. Here is what I have tried:

```
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class fullscreen_test extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener{
    public fullscreen_test() {
        this.setUndecorated(true); //remove title bar
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true); //always on top!!!
        this.setResizable(false); //unresizable
        this.setVisible(true);
        int xsize =(int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
        int ysize = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
        this.setSize(xsize, ysize); //set the size equal to the screen size
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this); //mousemotionlistener to show title bar
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fullscreen_test ft = new fullscreen_test();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if (e.getY() <= 1){
            if(src instanceof JFrame){
                ((JFrame) src).setUndecorated(false); //This is where eclipse says the error is.
            }
        }
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {} // required by the MouseMotionListener interface
}
```

but this code produces the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.
at java.awt.Frame.setUndecorated(Unknown Source)
```

I am totally stuck on what this error is. Any help will  be appreciated. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: It might be easier to implement your own "close" icon that appears when the user moves to the top.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated-boolean-) explains this quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to dispose your JFrame before you change the decorated state.

Try something like:

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    Object src = e.getSource();
    if (e.getY() <= 1){
        if(src instanceof JFrame){
            JFrame frame = (JFrame) src;
            frame.dispose();
            frame.setUndecorated(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

inside your `mouseMoved` method.

What the [JFrame Documentation for dispose()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()) says is, that a call

`Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its subcomponents, and all of its owned children.`

Then the resources may be manipulated and afterwards

`The Window and its subcomponents can be made displayable again by rebuilding the native resources with a subsequent call to pack or show. [...]`

in this/your case `setVisible(true)`, what does the same thing

`[...] The states of the recreated Window and its subcomponents will be identical to the states of these objects at the point where the Window was disposed [...]`

Adressing your `setUndecorated(true)` call

`[...] (not accounting for additional modifications between those actions).`

Hope it works for your.
Otherwise do not hesitate to comment this post!

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked fine except that it has a horrible (don't mind the adjective) change in the JFrame. The JFrame suddenly disappears revealing the desktop screen beneath and then it reppears with the titlebar. Thank you very much, anyway!

Comment: You're welcome! If your only use case is quitting the window, then i would advise you to implement a custom close button. (like @Steve Smith suggested)

Comment: If you think this answers your question, then accept it or otherwise sharpen your original question... Thank you very much!

Comment: What does @Steve Smith mean by "implementing my own close button"? Should I create my own close button and place it at the top?

Comment: Well, that leaves me to create maximize and minimize buttons as well.

Comment: As i mentioned above, it strongly depends on your use case(s)

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated-boolean-) states:

> This method can only be called while the frame is not displayable.

And a bit later in the same documentation:

> **Throws:** `IllegalComponentStateException` - if the frame is displayable

So there is simply no way to show a native title bar on a visible undecorated window.

However… you can show a “fake” title bar, provided by the cross platform look-and-feel:

```
((JFrame) src).getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
```

This is done by the look-and-feel, not by the native desktop system, so it does not require re-creating a native window.  The downside is that the title bar will not look exactly like a native title bar.